# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'CrashlyticsDelegate' when compiling Objective C++ file

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, objective-c++, google-fabric

Sample Project: https://github.com/mike011/CrashlyticsDelegateExample

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new Swift Project
2. Add in Crashlytics via a Podfile and make sure use_frameworks! is listed
3. Create the following extension:

`extension AppDelegate: CrashlyticsDelegate {
    func crashlyticsDidDetectReport(forLastExecution report: CLSReport) { }
}`

4. Add an Objective C++ file.
5. Add the following import to the new file

`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "CrashlyticsSampleApp-Swift.h"`

6. Compile

The error "Cannot find protocol declaration for 'CrashlyticsDelegate' is produced from the 'CrashlyticsSampleApp-Swift.h' file.

[image: **KABOOM!**]

Environment: MacOS 10.14 with xCode 9.4

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a bridging header for obj-c/swift and add the following import to it:

```
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
```

I haven't tested, but you probably can get away with it by adding that import to your sample objc file (`ObjectiveCMMFile.mm`) if you do not need the bridging header (would be great if you could confirm).